# (iphone) How to access CGRect member variable inside c++ class?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

i have a c++ class with CGrect variable and i'm getting segfault when trying to access it.

```
class Parent
{
 //with some virtual functions/dtors
};

class Child
{ 
  public:
    void SetRect(CGRect rect) { mRect = rect; } 
    CGRect GetRect() { return mRect; }
    int GetIndex() { return mIndex; }

  private:
    CGRect mRect;
    int    mIndex;
};
```

i'm doing

```
 CGRect rect = childPtr->GetRect();
```

from object c code and it segfaults.
I printed *childPtr just before the call and rect looks fine with intended data value.

```
int index = childPtr->GetIndex();
```

from same object c code(*.mm), works fine though.

Any idea why I'm getting segfaults?
Thank you

- edit -

It's got something to do with virtual functions.

(gdb) p singlePuzzlePiece->GetRect()

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000001
0x00000001 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (at 0x1) will be abandoned.
(gdb)

Somehow, the function is not properly compiled?

Comment: Looking at the code you gave us, it seems like it should work. Should Child be derived from Parent? Is GetRect() a virtual function in Parent? If so, is what's its implementation and is childPtr a Child* or a Parent*? I think we need more context.

Comment: There are child1, child2 and yes need to be derived from Parent. GetRect() is pure virtual at Parent. childPtr is type of Parent*. What bogs me is the fact CGRect is just c struct as far as I know..

Comment: I also tried static_cast ing ptr to Child* before the call

Comment: I see now that it's got nothing to do with CGRect, all the virtual function calls lead to segfaults.

Comment: found the problem. the ptr was deleted before the call.. silly me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

in objective C to get to the rect variables
u do this

> int indexX = rect.origin.x
>
> int indexY = rect.origin.y

etc..